# soap ui response error

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am getting an error like below when I load wsdl file in soap ui and after running it gives error like this in xml wizard.Ater giving some values to name and gender also it is showing the error.

This is the xsd file

```
<xsd:element name="helloworldRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="gender" type="string" maxOccurs="1"
                minOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="helloworldResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="greetings" type="string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:element>
```

Helloendpoint.java

```
public class HelloEndPoint {
@Autowired      
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://com.output.jaxBclasses";
private static final String LOCALPART = "helloworldRequest";
@PayloadRoot(localPart = LOCALPART, namespace = NAMESPACE_URI)
@ResponsePayload
public String handleStudentRequest(@RequestPayload HelloworldRequest request1) throws TransformerConfigurationException
{
    String gender=(String) request1.getGender();
    String name=(String) request1.getName();
       System.out.println(gender);
       System.out.println(name);
       String output="Hello"+name;
    System.out.println(output);
    return output;}}
```

This is the look after wisdal import

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:com="http://com.output.jaxBclasses">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <com:helloworldRequest>
         <com:name>?</com:name>
         <com:gender>?</com:gender>
      </com:helloworldRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

After running this I am getting error like below one.

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to internalize message; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:204)
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to internalize message
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.init(MessageImpl.java:515)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.&lt;init&gt;(MessageImpl.java:304)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.&lt;init&gt;(Message1_1Impl.java:67)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:61)
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:182)
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre></p><p><b>root cause</b> <pre>com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPVersionMismatchException: Cannot create message: incorrect content-type for SOAP version. Got: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8 Expected: text/xml
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.init(MessageImpl.java:382)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.&lt;init&gt;(MessageImpl.java:304)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.&lt;init&gt;(Message1_1Impl.java:67)
    com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:61)
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:182)
    org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:58)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:90)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.57 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.57</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: change your content type to text/xml

Comment: @NaveenRamawat I am new to xml & spring web service. Can you tell me where I need to add content type?

Comment: If I am not wrong you are sending request through SoapUI, In soapui you can see media type drop down on in where you make requests

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the WSDL, but it looks like SOAP-UI is recognizing the WSDL as a SOAP 1.2 contract (hence the application/soap+xml header and http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope namespace) but the actual service seems to require a SOAP 1.1 request (which would have text/xml content type and http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ request namespace).

You can see a comparison here: http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Request-Differences-SOAP-1-1-and-1-2.html

If this is the problem, the fault lies with the service provider who is advertising the wrong contract via the WSDL.  You might be able to get around this by copying the WSDL locally and modifying it to make it a SOAP 1.1 contract and regenerating your SOAP-UI requests.